# Calendar view in iPad Mini running iOS 9

Tags: calendar, ios

I can't seem to adjust my calendar view to see 5 days under the week view with my iPad Mini running iOS 9.  How do I change the setup?  I don't see an option in settings.

Answer (score 1):

The few things you can change in the native calendar app are under settings at the bottom of Mail, Contacts, Calendars:

[image]

You would need to download a custom calendar app to change the week view of your calendar data. The best I can manage is changing the week start date, which changes things everywhere.